# css relative positioned div text content expanding and overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to prevent a relative positioned div text content from overflowing outside of the bounds.

Check this [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5huqxys/) to show the problem

[image]

```css
.parent {
  margin: 5px;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: pink;
}

.details {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14pt;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.detail1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.detail2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="details">
    <div class="detail1">
      lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext
    </div>
    <div class="detail2">
      lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the .details is overflowing the parent element so overflow need to go to parent

Comment: @TemaniAfif that still doesn't show the two sets of text evenly in 50%  split of the allocated parent size ,,, i expect 50px for `detail1` and 50px for `detail2` and all contained within their spaces with no overflow

Comment: for that you need to restrict the height of .details not parent

Comment: I dont understand what you expect: both text to be truncated ? only second text ? the parent to adapt to its content ?

Comment: a.) there is no `position: relative` in your code anywhere plus it's not clear what relative position should have to do with the problem (?) b) you are not describing what you want to happen with the overflowing contents – be cut off completely or scrollable inside the parent?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind using height and overflow on exact same elements as you is `line clamp`

```css
  .parent {
        margin: 5px;
        max-height: 100px;
        max-width: 400px;
        background: pink;
    }
    
    .details {
         width: 100%;
         text-align: center;
         font-size: 14pt;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .detail1 {
      grid-row: 1;
    }
    
    .detail2 {
      grid-row: 2;
    }

.common {
  line-height: 25px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="details">
        <div class="detail1 common">
           lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext
        </div>
        <div class="detail2 common">
     lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add **overflow: hidden;** or remove **max-height** from parent.

```css
.parent {
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 100px;
    background: pink;
}

.details {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 14pt;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
 }

.detail1 {
    grid-row: 1;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.detail2 {
    grid-row: 2;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="details">
        <div class="detail1">
           lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext
        </div>
        <div class="detail2">
           lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext 
           lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can change max-height unit from px to vh it will work for you

```css
.parent {
    margin: 5px;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 400px;
    background: pink;
}

.details {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 14pt;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
 }

.detail1 {
    grid-row: 1;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.detail2 {
    grid-row: 2;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="details">
        <div class="detail1">
           lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext lotsoftext
        </div>
        <div class="detail2">
           lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext 
           lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext lotsmoretext 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```